# Python проверка наличия данных в sys.stdin

Tags: python, input

Как проверить есть ли данные для чтения в sys.stdin, чтобы программа не останавливалась в ожидании ввода, если их нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно посмотреть, что происходит, если  `timeout` близкий к нулю передать в [`input_with_timeout()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/4279). На Unix, чтобы узнать есть ли данные для чтения:

```
import select

ready, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [],[], 0)
```

На Windows, при вводе с консоли:

```
import msvcrt

ready = msvcrt.kbhit()
```

В качестве альтернативы, можно использовать асинхронный ввод/вывод (потоки, asyncio, O_NONBLOCK). [Примеры для неблокирующего чтения вывода внешней команды](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375427/4279).