# Как получить getch в цикле while без ожидания ввода?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как с помощью модуля threading сделать так, чтобы цикл while печатал "spam", пока пользователь не нажмет "q"?

```
while 1:
   print("spam")
   a = msvcrt.getch()
   if a == "q":
      break
   time.sleep(0.5)
```

нужно что-то вроде этого, только без ожидания нажатия клавиши.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python проверка наличия данных в sys.stdin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/744911/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
from threading import Thread
try:
    from msvcrt import getch
except ImportError:
    import sys
    import tty, termios
    def getch():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch


run = True

def ticker():
    while run:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Spam')


Thread(target=ticker, daemon=True).start()

while run:
    if getch() == b'q':
        run = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала проверяете, была ли нажата какая-то клавиша с помощью `kbhit()`, потом уже считываете нажатую клавишу с помощью `getch()`:

```
import msvcrt
import time

while True:
    print("spam")
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        a = msvcrt.getch()
        print(a)
        if a == b'q':
            break
    time.sleep(0.5)
```